# Put three.js inside another element in HTML

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying put the Canvas Lines three.js inside another div but this doesn't working. When I try, the JS put the canvas at the very end of the body.S Anyone can tell me why?

I want that canvas stay inside of `<div id="canvas_3d"></div>` and that JS don't put the section at the very end of the body.

HTML:

```
<section class="lc_hero hero_fulHeight" style="background-image: url('img/hero_top.jpg');">
  <div id="canvas_3d"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <%# <div class="col-md-1"></div> %>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="lc_hero__heading">
          <h1 class="head_white"><span>L</span>aboratório de <span>In</span>ovação e <span>C</span>ompetições de <span>E</span>ngenharia</h1>
          <p>Projetos que vão além da <span>faculdade!</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lc_hero__scroll_down">
      <%= svg "scroll_down" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Javascript:

```
var mouseX = 0,
  mouseY = 0,

  windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2,
  windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2,

  SEPARATION = 200,
  AMOUNTX = 10,
  AMOUNTY = 10,

  camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  var container, separation = 100,
    amountX = 50,
    amountY = 50,
    particles, particle;

  var container = document.getElementById('canvas_3d');
  // container = document.createElement('div');
  // container.className = "canvas_3d" 
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 100;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // particles

  var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
  var material = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial({

    color: 0xffffff,
    program: function (context) {

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(0, 0, 0.5, 0, PI2, true);
      context.fill();

    }

  });

  var points = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    particle = new THREE.Sprite(material);
    particle.position.x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    particle.position.y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    particle.position.z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    particle.position.normalize();
    particle.position.multiplyScalar(Math.random() * 10 + 450);
    particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 10;
    scene.add(particle);

    points.push(particle.position);
  }

  // lines

  var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);

  var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    opacity: 0.5
  }));
  scene.add(line);

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
  document.addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false);
  document.addEventListener('touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false);

  //

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}

function onWindowResize() {

  windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
  windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

//

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

  mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
  mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;

}

function onDocumentTouchStart(event) {

  if (event.touches.length > 1) {

    event.preventDefault();

    mouseX = event.touches[0].pageX - windowHalfX;
    mouseY = event.touches[0].pageY - windowHalfY;

  }

}

function onDocumentTouchMove(event) {

  if (event.touches.length == 1) {

    event.preventDefault();

    mouseX = event.touches[0].pageX - windowHalfX;
    mouseY = event.touches[0].pageY - windowHalfY;

  }

}

//

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  render();

}

function render() {

  camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * .05;
  camera.position.y += (-mouseY + 200 - camera.position.y) * .05;
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Remove this line `document.body.appendChild(container);`. You are moving the element to the end of the body by appending it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `document.body.appendChild(container);` from your javascript. That is moving your container to the end of the body element.

Comment: This woks very well. Thanks :D